# Associate some value with Image that represents that value

Tags: c#, wpf, image, random, onclick

Is it possible for an image to be associated with some value?

I'm trying to have a button where you press click it and a random image comes up. That image would represent a value either 10, 20, or close the program.

How can I assign an image which shows up randomly to have a set value and increment those as you go until you get the close image to show?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but why use an image.  Just use a textblock to display a number in the font and color of your choosing.

Comment: I could do that, but I need to associate a certain image with a value in the c# code so it can increment that value that I give it as a "Your score". btw Im making a game.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `Image` control? Than you can use the `Tag` property to store a second value (in addition to the `ImageSource Image` property).

```
var random = new Random();
var x = random.Next(0, 3)];
myImage.Source = myImagesSources[x]
myImage.Tag = x;//or what you want
```

You can also derivate a class from `ImageSource` and pass the value to the instance.

```
public class Test : ImageSource
{
    public int Value{get;set;}
    //implementing the necessary code for ImageSource
```

Or you use a `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>` or a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` to store the images with there values.